# CheckDate Function Adds a Month When Invalid

Tags: php, validation, date, if-statement

I am determining the day of the week from the date.  I added an array to print out the actual month instead of the number for the month.  It works properly for a correct date.  But when I look up an invalid date, the checkdate function works but it moves the month up one when displaying the invalid date.  I know it has something to do with the monthName because when I leave it as a month number ($month), it works correctly.  Any ideas why?

```
<?Php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$todo=$_POST['todo'];

if(isset($todo) and $todo=="submit")
    {
      $month=$_POST['month'];
      $dt=$_POST['dt'];
      $year=$_POST['year'];
      $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, "$month", "$dt", "$year");
      $monthName = date("F", $timestamp);

        if (checkdate($month, $dt, $year)) 
            {
            "<br>";
            echo "$monthName $dt, $year was (or will be) on a " . \date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, "$month", "$dt", "$year")) . "<br>";
            } 

        else 
            {
            echo $error = "The date $monthName $dt, $year is invalid";
            }
      }
?>

<h2>Enter a Date and I'll Tell You the Day of the Week</h2>

<form method=post name=f1 action=''><input type=hidden name='todo' value="submit">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" >
<tr><td  align=left>   
Month <select name=month value=''>Select Month</option>
<option value='01'>January</option>
<option value='02'>February</option>
<option value='03'>March</option>
<option value='04'>April</option>
<option value='05'>May</option>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an invalid date, then I guess that mktime is producing a timestamp for $month + 1 depending on the invalid date you are passing. eg 30th February would be converted to 1st March.

[Proof](http://3v4l.org/6SXlr)

Personally, I would ditch mktime and use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) for this. Something like:-

```
$month=2;
$dt=30;
$year=2014;

if(!checkdate($month, $dt, $year)){
    echo "$dt " . \DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $month)->format('F') . " $year is not a valid date";
} else {
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d m Y', "$dt $month $year");
    echo $date->format('jS F Y') . " will be a " . $date->format('l');
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/Vc73i)

Comment: I guess I could redefine the $monthName in the else statement.  But is there any other fix?